# @EnvironmentObject is passed after init is called

Tags: swift, swiftui

*`@EnviromentObject` is passed down when the body is called, so it doesn't yet exist during the initialization phase of the View struct.* Ok, that is clear. The question is, how do you solve the following problem?

```swift
struct MyCollectionScreen: View {
        
    // Enviroment
    @EnvironmentObject var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    
    // Internal dependencies
    @ObservedObject private var provider: CoreDataProvider
    
    init() {
      provider = CoreDataProvider(viewContext: viewContext)
    }
}
```

The previous doesn't compile and throws the error:

> 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized.

That is because I am trying to use the `@EnviromentObject` object before it is actually set.

For this, I am trying a couple of things but I am not super happy with any of them

**1. Initialize my `provider` after the `init()` method**

```swift
struct MyCollectionScreen: View {

    // Enviroment
    @EnvironmentObject var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext

    // Internal dependencies
    @ObservedObject private var provider: CoreDataProvider

    var body: some View {
    }.onAppear {
      loadProviders()
    }
    
    mutating func loadProviders() {
      provider = CoreDataProvider(viewContext: viewContext)
    }
}
```

but that, doesn't compile either and you get the following error within the `onAppear` block:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable

**2. Pass the viewContext in the init method and forget about Environment objects:**

This second solution works, but I don't like having to pass the `viewContext` to most of my views in the init methods, I kind of liked the Environment object idea.

```swift
struct MyCollectionScreen: View {
            
        // Internal dependencies
        @ObservedObject private var provider: CoreDataProvider
        
        init(viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
          provider = CoreDataProvider(viewContext: viewContext)
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are using the SwiftUI Life cycle, have you tried having let viewContext = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext?

Comment: That is one I am using, yes. The problem is I want that to be injected so I can easily change between the preview and the shared instances without having to modify every single place where I use the viewContext.

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in @FetchRequest instead of a custom object? In SwiftUI the View structs are supposed to be the primary encapsulation mechanism not objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `viewContext` in `CoreDataProvider` an optional, and then set it `onAppear`

```
struct MyCollectionScreen: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext

    @ObservedObject private var provider = CoreDataProvider()

    var body: some View {
      Text("Hello")
        .onAppear {
          provider.viewContext = viewContext
        }
}
```

Downside is that you'll now have an optional.

I think that what I would do is to create `CoreDataProvider` at the same time `viewContext` is created, and pass it as an environment object as well.